# Correctly merge and filter GPS coordinates from LINESTRING in R's sf package

Tags: postgis, r, openstreetmap, sf, sfcgal

I have an SFC object with 2508 features of LINESTRING geometry type in R's sf package.

When I extract the GPS coordinates and plot them, I notice some parts of the trace are connected in the wrong direction. I've tried using `st_union` and `st_cast` to create a MULTILINESTRING and then merging the lines using `st_line_merge`, but I'm still left with a few points that don't align correctly.

How can I solve this issue and filter out these problematic points? Is it possible to remove line crossings to resolve this problem? See code and example plots for more details.

You can find the code and data to replicate this problem here in this zip file:

[Data and R code](https://wormhole.app/9DaOE#oqSXria3Anc_Yv3o_PPhzQ)

**UPDATE:** I added another example where the previous aobject a is also present:

[Example_2](https://wormhole.app/kjqKW#_ouLCfWZP1TCMYoS6k5N9Q)

I have the following SF object, **a**:

```
Geometry set for 2508 features
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension: XY
Bounding box: xmin: 10.4244175, ymin: 47.4499185, xmax: 11.8835832, ymax: 48.151472
Geodetic CRS: WGS 84
First 5 geometries:
LINESTRING (11.829711 48.1091401, 11.8297571 48...
LINESTRING (11.8336202 48.115214, 11.8336202 48...
LINESTRING (11.8333238 48.1269572, 11.8330935 4...
LINESTRING (11.833845 48.1271528, 11.8335776 48...
LINESTRING (11.8341994 48.1273387, 11.8341718 4..
```

If I just extract the GPS coordinates and plot them, I get this kind of trace:

trace <- as.data.table(st_coordinates(a))

```
             X          Y       L1
    1: 11.8297110 48.1091401    1
    2: 11.8297571 48.1092801    1
    3: 11.8297974 48.1094009    1
    4: 11.8298619 48.1095555    1
    5: 11.8299231 48.1096592    1
   ---                           
22136: 10.6247701 47.8822685 2507
22137: 10.6249838 47.8827939 2507
22138: 10.6249838 47.8827939 2508
22139: 10.6250719 47.8830256 2508
22140: 10.6251034 47.8831243 2508
```

As you can see, there are some parts of the trace which are connected in the wrong direction.

[image]

[image]

If I do the following:

```
b <- st_union(st_cast(a, "MULTILINESTRING"))
```

which creates:

```
Geometry set for 1 feature
Geometry type: MULTILINESTRING
Dimension: XY
Bounding box: xmin: 10.4244175, ymin: 47.4499185, xmax: 11.8835832, ymax: 48.151472
Geodetic CRS: WGS 84
MULTILINESTRING ((11.829711 48.1091401, 11.8297...
```

If I get the coordinates now and display them, it creates this trace:

[image]

which is different but not better.

So I try to merge the lines:

```
c <- lines_merged <- st_cast(st_line_merge(b), "LINESTRING")
```

And if I plot this trace:

[image]

I'm almost there, except for 3 places which you can see by these straight lines.

How could I solve my problem and filter out those couple of points? Is it maybe possible to remove line crossings and solve this problem this way?

Data is from a PostGIS Database with openstreetmap which was importet with `osm2pgsql` from a pbf file downoaded at geofabrik.

Comment: Bit confused here. Your data download creates a `b` object which is 2508 LINESTRING objects, but in your text you show `b` as a single feature MULTILINESTRING.  Is the `b` in the download really the same as `a` in your text?

Comment: B is casted from a,  b <- st_union(st_cast(a, "MULTILINESTRING")), I can also add a if that helps

Comment: @Spacedman I added another example where a and b are present.